# How do I force booting in text mode?

Tags: debian, boot, graphics, init.d

Newer Linux distributions have the idea to boot into graphics modes.

The grub menu does this.

The init.d system does this.

X does this.

I can justify X. But both grub and init.d have only caused me troubles and never given me any joys. I am now installing on an old system that does not have *any* fancy graphics, so I would like to tell Debian *not* to touch the graphics systems *at* *all*.

Right now I have gotten grub to stay in text mode:

```
/etc/default/grub:
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
```

Followed by: update-grub

And X is disabled by not installing X.

The graphics system is still touched during init.d. I have the feeling it is some VESA mode that is being changed.

Where do I disable this, so it stays in text mode?

System info:

```
Debian stable:
# uname -a
Linux grb 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Edit:

Adding this to /etc/default/grub gets rid of part of it (thanks to TAFKA):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vga=normal nomodeset"
```

But the below seems to clear my scroll back buffer, too, and change the fonts:

```
[info] setting up console font and keymap
```

Putting 'exit 0' in '/etc/init.d/console-setup' works around this, but does not seem to be "the Debian way".

So the question is now down to: How to disable 'console-setup' the Debian way?

Comment: Searching for "grub disable framebuffer", you ll find all you need.. example https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer

Comment: @rMistero link broken.

Answer (score 8):

> But init.d screws me over by changing into a screen resolution that my monitor/graphics card does not support. I have the feeling it is some VESA mode that is being changed.

I don't think that's an `init` process.  That's the kernel.  It occurs during the boot messages, right?

If you compile the kernel without **framebuffer** support, it should not happen.  If you are using a stock kernel, it's possibly a module.

```
find /lib/modules -name fb.ko
```

Remove that if found, run `depmod`, and reboot.

If that module is not there but you have a `/dev/fb[N]` (where `[N]` is a number, probably `0`), you need to do it some other way.  Try adding:

```
vga=normal nomodeset
```

to the kernel invocation line in `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

Debian Jessie now uses `systemd` and the concept of *runlevel* should be modified into *target units*.

For starting Jessie in text mode without removing Gnome or LXDE it's then sufficient to modify this symlink as follow :

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /lib/systemd/system/default.target
```

This action is practiaclly the same of setting a *text* runlevel on `/etc/inittab` in the previous versions.

In Fedora 21 it's practically the same, but the system helps a bit more:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered looking at /etc/inittab? It is where run levels are initialized. By default level 5 is the graphical run level, and level 3 (or 2 in Debian's case) are text mode. You would have to invoke a 'startx' to go into graphical mode.

Alan

Comment: This is an alternative to the OP's "don't install X" solution, but it does not help with the text console video mode change, which is his real problem.